# VBA Printer and Printers object requires installing Reference library?

Tags: excel, vba, reference, printers

I have a question for Printer object and Printers object in Excel VBA. Is any Reference library required to install in the Tool->Reference before we can use Pinter and Printers object?

I run below code, and get error "object is required" for line `For Each prt In Printers`. The Printers object is empty and `prt`-object is Nothing.

```
Sub ListPrinters()
    Dim prt As Printer
    For Each prt In Printers
        Debug.Print Prt.deviceName
    Next prt
End Sub
```

I tried to add reference library in Tool-> reference menu, and could not find any reference for Printer or Printers.

Answer (score 4):

`Application.Printers` does not exist in Excel or Word, it exists only in Access (didn't check for Powerpoint or any other MS Applications).

Alternative is to use the method `EnumPrinterConnections` of the Windows Scripting Host:

```
Sub ListPrinters2()
    Dim i As Long
    With CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        For i = 1 To .EnumPrinterConnections.Count Step 2
          Debug.Print .EnumPrinterConnections(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

The loop might look a little bit strange with the `Step 2`. Reason is that every printer has 2 entries in the list, the first gets the port, the second the printer name.